# Retrieving environment variable with Robot

Tags: robotframework

According to the docs here

```
Get Environment Variable    (name, default=None)    
Returns the value of an environment variable with the given name.
If no such environment variable is set, returns the default value, if given. Otherwise fails the test case.
Returned variables are automatically decoded to Unicode using the system encoding.
Note that you can also access environment variables directly using the variable syntax %{ENV_VAR_NAME}.
```

I should be able to use

`${env_var}=  Get Environment Variable  STAGING_SERVER
Log To Console  ${env_var}`

But Robot keeps complaining that there's no such variable. But when I flip over to my terminal and run `echo $STAGING_SERVER` I get desired output.

What can I do ?

Comment: Try using "Get Environment Variables" to retrieve a dictionary of all available environment variables. See if STAGING_SERVER is listed as a key.

Comment: @BrianO'Neill  I ran it and it doesn't show the key. I used `export` to set the env variable. Do I need to use something else ?

Comment: When you run your robot test, are you running it in the same terminal? How are you running the robot test? Perhaps it's running in a separate process that doesn't have that environment variable.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley  I'm running two terminal sessions. One where I'm running Django development server and the other one for running Robot tests.

Comment: Are you certain the environment variable is set in both? Can you see the environment variable from the shell in both terminals?

Answer (score 1):

The variable is not set in the terminal you are using.
See this example in Windows command window:

```
C:\Testes>echo %STAGING_SERVER%
%STAGING_SERVER%

C:\Testes>robot -t env_var Example.robot
==============================================================================
Example
==============================================================================
env var                                                               | FAIL |
Environment variable 'STAGING_SERVER' does not exist.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Example                                                               | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Testes\output.xml
Log:     C:\Testes\log.html
Report:  C:\Testes\report.html

C:\Testes>set STAGING_SERVER="The variable is set"

C:\Testes>robot -t env_var Example.robot
==============================================================================
Example
==============================================================================
env var                                                               ."The variable is set"
env var                                                               | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Example                                                               | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Testes\output.xml
Log:     C:\Testes\log.html
Report:  C:\Testes\report.html

C:\Testes>echo %STAGING_SERVER%
"The variable is set"
```

For completeness, this is the test suite:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
env var
    ${env_var}=    Get Environment Variable    STAGING_SERVER
    Log To Console    ${env_var}
```

Answer (score 1):

although you pasted [docu](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Get%20Environment%20Variable) for "Get Environment Variable" from "OperatingSystem" library you missed a tiny but helpful information:

> .... access environment variables directly using the variable syntax %{ENV_VAR_NAME}

So you can easily adapt that in your robot code (eg STAGING_SERVER)

```
${env_var}=  %{STAGING_SERVER}
Log To Console  ${env_var}
```

Comment: Bonus tip: Set a default value like `%{STAGING_SERVER=127.0.0.1}`